# time series sliding window with occurrence counts

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am trying to get a count between two timestamped values:

for example:

```
time    letter
  1     A
  4     B
  5     C
  9     C
  18    B
  30    A
  30    B
```

I am dividing time to time windows: 1+ 30 / 30 
then I want to know how many A B C in each time window of size 1

```
timeseries  A  B  C
1           1  0  0
2           0  0  0
...
30          1  1  0
```

this shoud give me a table of 30 rows and 3 columns: A B C of ocurancess

The problem is the data is taking to long to be break down because it iterates through all master table every time to slice the data eventhough thd data is already sorted

```
master = mytable  

minimum = master.timestamp.min()
maximum = master.timestamp.max()

window = (minimum + maximum) / maximum

wstart = minimum
wend = minimum + window

concurrent_tasks = []

while ( wstart <= maximum ):
    As = 0
    Bs = 0
    Cs = 0
    for d, row in master.iterrows():
        ttime = row.timestamp
        if ((ttime >= wstart) & (ttime < wend)):
            #print (row.channel)
            if (row.channel == 'A'):
                As = As + 1
            elif (row.channel == 'B'):
                Bs = Bs + 1
            elif (row.channel == 'C'):
                Cs = Cs + 1


    concurrent_tasks.append([m_id, As, Bs, Cs])

    wstart = wstart + window
    wend = wend + window
```

Could you help me in making this perform better ? i want to use map function and i want to prevent python from looping through all the loop every time.

This is part of big data and it taking days to finish ?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

There is a faster approach - [pd.get_dummies()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
In [116]: pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('time')['letter'])
Out[116]:
      A  B  C
time
1     1  0  0
4     0  1  0
5     0  0  1
9     0  0  1
18    0  1  0
30    1  0  0
30    0  1  0
```

If you want to "compress" (group) it by `time`:

```
In [146]: pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('time')['letter']).groupby(level=0).sum()
Out[146]:
      A  B  C
time
1     1  0  0
4     0  1  0
5     0  0  1
9     0  0  1
18    0  1  0
30    1  1  0
```

or using [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(token_pattern=r"\b\w+\b", stop_words=None)

r = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv.fit_transform(df.groupby('time')['letter'].agg(' '.join)),
                       index=df['time'].unique(),
                       columns=df['letter'].unique(),
                       default_fill_value=0)
```

Result:

```
In [143]: r
Out[143]:
    A  B  C
1   1  0  0
4   0  1  0
5   0  0  1
9   0  0  1
18  0  1  0
30  1  1  0
```

If we want to list all `times` from `1` to `30`:

```
In [153]: r.reindex(np.arange(r.index.min(), r.index.max()+1)).fillna(0).astype(np.int8)
Out[153]:
    A  B  C
1   1  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   0  1  0
5   0  0  1
6   0  0  0
7   0  0  0
8   0  0  0
9   0  0  1
10  0  0  0
11  0  0  0
12  0  0  0
13  0  0  0
14  0  0  0
15  0  0  0
16  0  0  0
17  0  0  0
18  0  1  0
19  0  0  0
20  0  0  0
21  0  0  0
22  0  0  0
23  0  0  0
24  0  0  0
25  0  0  0
26  0  0  0
27  0  0  0
28  0  0  0
29  0  0  0
30  1  1  0
```

or using Pandas approach:

```
In [159]: pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('time')['letter']) \
     ...:   .groupby(level=0) \
     ...:   .sum() \
     ...:   .reindex(np.arange(r.index.min(), r.index.max()+1), fill_value=0)
     ...:
Out[159]:
      A  B  C
time
1     1  0  0
2     0  0  0
3     0  0  0
4     0  1  0
5     0  0  1
6     0  0  0
7     0  0  0
8     0  0  0
9     0  0  1
10    0  0  0
...  .. .. ..
21    0  0  0
22    0  0  0
23    0  0  0
24    0  0  0
25    0  0  0
26    0  0  0
27    0  0  0
28    0  0  0
29    0  0  0
30    1  1  0

[30 rows x 3 columns]
```

**UPDATE:**

Timing:

```
In [163]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [164]: %timeit pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('time')['letter'])
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

In [165]: %timeit df.set_index('time').letter.str.get_dummies()
1 loop, best of 3: 914 ms per loop
```

Comment: fill_value=0 on reindex

Comment: @piRSquared, yeah, i'm always forgetting about this parameter. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Not sure which is faster but this should work as well. df.set_index('time').letter.str.get_dummies(). Probably yours.

Comment: @piRSquared, wow! take a look at timing - i'm shocked... Didn't expect such a difference...

Comment: that's good information. I'll avoid the string accessor when I can

Comment: I'm still on 0.20.1 - it coukd be fixed in later versions - i didn't check it up

Comment: it worked like magic with less than 15 minutes and that is really good because now I can sample  more. Is there a parameter which allow me to have a shift in the re-sampling process after storing the file with the smallest window size ? for example, i want to re-sample with larger size but with shift ( sliding window) ?

Comment: i did. hope that it is explained well please take a look [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329115/shifting-with-re-sampling-in-time-series-data)